# Quit smoking supported by mental training

Tags: neuroscience, brain-training, addiction, nicotine

Given that mental training/workout releases acetylcholine (something I read in a popular-scientific book and on [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_improvement#Psychopharmacology), see also below) , and that acetylcholine and nicotine bind to the same receptors. Is it possible to reduce the craving for nicotine by doing a brain-training task such as mathematics or memorising poetry?

Comment: could you give a citation for the "mental training releases acetylcholine" claim?  neurotransmitter release isn't a simple yes/no question.  the effects greatly depend on the context, brain area, extent of release, etc.

Comment: @honi from [Memory Improvement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_improvement#Psychopharmacology): "Evidence that aspects of memory can be improved by action on selective neurotransmitter systems, such as the cholinergic system **which releases acetylcholine**, has possible therapeutic benefits for patients with cognitive disorders.[(21)](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/290/5500/2275)"

Answer (score -1):

There is many methods to change craving for nicotine. You can train your brain by the suggesting to yourself (or by hipnotherapeutists) something as: I don't need nicothine. When you are in the trance state for exemple or when you have highly good responses for hipnosis suggestions it will be usefull. In trance people have diffrent reality and their body tell them that i can do that and people can change even chemical responses of their bodies. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnotherapy

Another thing is that you can focus on mathematic or poetry so much that you forget about your bad habit and when you do it again and again its Pavlov's Dog effect that it will be automatic response for your psyche. For example - your mathematics will be the cure for the craving for nicotine. However if you stop doing your mathematic, you probably will be smoking again (old habits activate again without mathematics or poetry cure).

Comment: Do you have any sources for this?

Comment: Hi, EPOS.  Welcome to cogsci.SE.  We typically require peer-reviewed sources to back up your claims.  For example, you could cite a journal article that examined the efficacy of a hypnotherapy intervention for smoking cessation.  Wikipedia is usually not sufficient.  This is true for all answers you give--they require citing the relevant scientific literature.  If you're unfamiliar with the relevant literature, then you can either (1) familiarize yourself with it by reading some articles and citing them or (2) withhold giving an answer.

Comment: Can i give link for youtube video or is it treat like wikipedia website too? Some films are making by some scientific companies so it will be good or not if i give that exemples? Thanks for answearing - i'm new so explain me this.

Comment: Companies are there to make money, not provide good research material (or effective interventions).